# ModRewrite redirect to url from query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain

> http://mydomain.com/

And i need redirect from this link

> http://mydomain.com/?http://example.com

to

> http://example.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ %2\? [R=301,L]
```